# How can i cancel an order of a customer and reorder in Magento2 using REST API

Tags: rest, api, magento2

which end point should i use to cancel and reorder the user orders in magento 2. i tried like this. help me[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use POST methods for cancel order API. GET methods does not exits that's why you are getting route error.